# Discord Bot: This Python Code written for our discord bot to remember our book reading progress always returns zero. How can I make this work?

Tags: python, debugging, discord.py, bots

People in our Discord Bookclub, wanted our bot to remember our reading progress. For example, the following is how I want members to log progress:

**Member:** *-update Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy*
**Bot:** What's your progress?
**Member:** *Book 2, Chapter 20*
**Bot:** Noted

---

***The other day:***

**Member:** *-progress (username)*
**Bot:** (username) is currently at Book 2, Chapter 20

---

This is the code we have so far:

```py
import discord
import random
import os
from keep_online import keep_alive

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.emojis=True
client=discord.Client(intents=intents)

hg2g={
  "User1":0,
  "User2":0,
  "User3":0,
  "User4":0
}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username=str(message.author).split("#")[0]
    mess=message.content
```

However, this code is only returning `"0"` when progress is requested.

What am I doing wrong and how do I make it work? Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, for a start, extract a [mcve] which must (especially for Python!) be formatted correctly. Above code only tells you that `message` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I used [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#commands) instead of `on_message` as you can specify the command prefix, make an [error handler](https://vcokltfre.dev/tutorial/12-errors/) etc. You have to make one more import and modify `client` a little bit to use commands. Also, check out [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com), you can make a 512 MB database for free and I think it's necessary in your case because if you save everything in variables they will disappear after you stop your code.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-", intents=intents)
hg2g={}
another_book = {}

@client.command()
async def update(ctx, *, book_title):
    book_title = book_title.lower() # I used "lower()" to ignore if it's written in lowercase or not

    if book_title == "hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy": # you can add other books
        choosen_book = hg2g
    elif book_title == "another book": 
        choosen_book = another_book
    else:
        await ctx.send("Wait! I couldn't find this book in database!")
        return
    
    await ctx.send("What's your progress?")

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    choosen_book.update({msg.author.id : msg.content})
    await ctx.send("Noted")


@client.command()
async def progress(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, book_title):
    book_title = book_title.lower()

    if book_title == "hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy":
        msg = hg2g.get(user.id)
    elif book_title == "another book":
        msg = another_book.get(user.id)
    else:
        await ctx.send("I couldn't find this book in database!")
        return
    
    if msg is not None:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} is currently at: {msg}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} doesn't have any progress.")


@update.error
@progress.error
async def book_error(ctx, error: commands.CommandError): # if someone doesn't specify book title
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please specify book title and/or user!")
```